# Ruby Sum of amounts in enumerator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following enumerator

```
[
 #<User number: "23", amt: 1.0, amt1: 0.1>, 
 #<User number: "23", amt: 2.0, amt1: 0.1>, 
 #<User number: "24", amt: 3.0, amt1: 0.3>, 
 #<User number: "25", amt: 3.3, amt1: 0.4>
]
```

I am doing

```
users.each { |user| user.select { |a| a.inject(0){|sum, i| sum + ( amt - amt1) } }}
```

I get an error(undefined method inject for enumerator). What is wrong with the above syntax?

I need to calculate (amt - amt1) per user. if there are multiple rows, then should do an aggregate of all the rows per user.

Comment: @ArupRakshit i updated the error description in the quesiton.

Comment: Your code is misleading.. What is the purpose of `select` method ?

Comment: @ArupRakshit I am selecting each record.

Comment: what `inject` is doing?

Comment: So, what's your `users` like? And what do you want as output?

Comment: @Pinepara : Vimisha's answer worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
users = [
 #<User number: "23", amt: 1.0, amt1: 0.1>, 
 #<User number: "23", amt: 2.0, amt1: 0.1>, 
 #<User number: "24", amt: 3.0, amt1: 0.3>, 
 #<User number: "25", amt: 3.3, amt1: 0.4>
]

sum = {}
grouped_users = users.group_by{|user| user.number}
grouped_users.map{|number, users| sum[number] = users.sum{|u| u.amt - u.amt1}}
p sum
```

Comment: No need `&:+`, use only `:+`.

Comment: @Vimsha How can i calculate per user?

Comment: @Kumar: What do you want to calculate per user?

Comment: @Vimsha if u see i have two records for user 23... i need to do (amt - amt1) for both records. so i am saying per user.

Comment: This is solution is fine but I would avoid having to use a mutable variable like sum = {}

Answer (score 2):

A **functional** solution (without any extra mutable variables) using just `.group_by` and `.reduce`

```
users.group_by do |user| 
  user.number
end.map do |key, value| 
  User.new(number: key, 
           amt: value.reduce(0) { |acc, s| acc + (s.amt - s.amt1) })
end
```

It is very similar to [this question I answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22029251/aggregation-on-a-ruby-enumerable/22029660#22029660) yesterday. Check it out to see in detail a working example with an array of objects.

Answer (score 1):

The set up portion

```
users = [
{number: "23", amt: 1.0, amt1: 0.1},
{number: "23", amt: 2.0, amt1: 0.1},
{number: "24", amt: 3.0, amt1: 0.3},
{number: "25", amt: 3.3, amt1: 0.4}
]
users.map! { |user| OpenStruct.new user }
```

The below is what does the real thing, the above is just to create something similar to the OP's users

```
 Hash[users.group_by(&:number).map { |n, g| [n, g.inject(0) { |sum, user| sum += (user.amt - user.amt1) } ] } ]
#=> {"23"=>2.8, "24"=>2.7, "25"=>2.9}
```

OR

```
users.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |u, h| h[u.number] += (u.amt - u.amt1) }
#=> {"23"=>2.8, "24"=>2.7, "25"=>2.9}
```

Answer (score 1):

My pure Ruby take on it:

```
sum = users.group_by(&:number).each.with_object(Hash.new{0}) do |(n, users), sum|
  sum[n] += users.map { |u| u.amt - u.amt1 }.inject(:+)
end
```

How I would do it in Rails:

```
User.group("number").sum("amt - amt1")
```